# HTML5 как оформить с помощью семантических тегов список статей?

Tags: html5, разметка, теги, семантика

У меня есть список статей. Он состояит из названия статьи и описания, и ещё количество лайков показывается.

```
<div>
    <div><a href="Ссылка на статью">Называние статьи</a></div>
    <div>Описание статьи ( обычно несколько строк )</div>
    <div>5 лайков</div>
</div>
```

Как лучше семантически оформить этот блок. Его либо в `<article>` обернуть, либо в `<section>`?
Ссылку с названием думаю поместить в `<header>` а количество лайков в `<footer>`.

Comment: ну как-то это не красиво задавать вопрос по семантике про каждую свою внутреннюю страницу. я ж в предыдущем вопросе общий смысл объяснил. а дальше следует читать [Новые теги](http://htmlbook.ru/samlayout/verstka-na-html5/novye-tegi) и [Продвинутая семантика и доступность](https://webref.ru/layout/advanced-html-css/semantics-accessibility), и размышлять субъективно

Comment: я читал статьи, и там в них разное пишут про одни и теже семантические теги. Именно этот вопрос другой чем тот, я не понимаю для маленьких кусочков информации, которые являются чисто ссылочными что лучше использовать статью или секцию. Но думаю отчасти вы правы, но тем не менее вопросы разные.